# CoAP, how to understand "Options"

Tags: coap

Formatting a CoAP packet

[RFC 7252 CoAP][1]

In RFC 7252 Section 3, Figure 7 the third row, bytes 9 ... 16 or maybe more, is the Options field. I am unable to find anything that specifies how long the options field is. I understand that it can change, but unlike the Token field who's length is specified by field TKL, I cannot recognize where the length of the Options is specified.

Yes, I see sections 3.1 and 3.2 but am not able to understand what they are telling me.  The document states to reference the previous options.  OK, what do you do for the first message where there is no previous packet and no previous option?

When my code needs to send a CoAP message, how do I determine what options can be sent?  What values must be loaded into the packet to send, for example, no options?

Answer (score 11):

If you see Figure 8 in sec 3.1 on the RFC, bits 4-7 denote the length of the option value.

```
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
   +---------------+---------------+
   |  Option Delta | Option Length |   1 byte
   +---------------+---------------+
```

Bits 0-3 will tell you which option it is. This nibble only gives you the delta compared to the previous option encoded in this message. For the first option in the message, there is no previous option so the bits 0-3 give you the Option number.

Lets consider an example where you need to encode 2 options `Uri-Port` with value `7000` and `Uri-Path` with value `/temp` in a CoAP message. Options are always encoded in increasing order of the Option numbers. So you first encode `Uri-Port` which has Option number `7` and then `Uri-Path` with Option number `11`.

**Uri-Port**
As this is the first option in the message, the Option delta will be same as the Option number so `Option delta = 0x7`. Port value `7000` will take `2` bytes `(0x1B58)` so `Option length = 0x2`. So this Option will be encoded get encoded as `72 1b 58`.

**Uri-Path**
This is not the first Option in this message. Option delta for this option will be `this option number - prev option number` i.e. `11 - 7 = 4`. Encoding `temp` will take 4 bytes so `Option length = 4`. So this option would get encoded as `44 74 65 6d 70`

Note that this was for a simplified case where the Option number and length are not more than 12 bytes. When either of these is more than 12 bytes, you encode using the extended option delta/length as specified in the RFC.

Comment: You made my day!